# I need to print a field in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is the code. And have a private field called test.

```
<?php
    class Boo { 
        private $test = array( 123, '456'); 
        function __construct($x,$y){ 
            $opts = array( 
                'http'=>array( 'header' => 'Connection: close')
            ); 
        $context = stream_context_create($opts); 
            $this->test = file_get_contents('http://localhost/y.php?a='.$x.'&b='.$y, false, $context); 
        } 

        public static function Boo($x,$y) { 
            return json_encode(array($y, $x+$y)); 
        } 


    } 

    if(isset($_REQUEST['a'])){ 
        print Boo::Boo($_GET['a'],$_GET['b']); 
    } 
    else { 
        // print (new Boo(11,12)); 
    } 

?>
```

I can only write a function to print the `$test` value without making any modifications.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To access private properties you must write a `getter` method in your class.

```
public function getTest() {
    return $this->test;
}
```

Then you can call the `getter` method like this:

```
$myObj = new Boo();
var_dump($myObj->getTest());
```

If you don't want to write a getter method then you have to set the property's accessibility to `public` to access it outside of the class scope.

But I think you mix up static and non-static content in your class.

Btw class methods should start with lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

It's private and therefore not accessible from outside the class. From inside you can always access it, but you need a getter to bring it to the public.

Comment: this is how i got the problem to solve... sadly i didn't understood much.